# AWS CDK: Handling Security Group Deletion Failure Due to Dependent ENIs

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-security-group, elastic-network-interface

My cdk stack will not destroy because of dependent Elastic Netwrok Interface (ENIs). The stack includes a Lamda function and a security group, and even through the lambda function is deleted correctly, the security group deletion fails due to these lingering ENIs.

I beleve there is a related issue in terrafrom that was resolved but no such luck in cdk. https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/10329

It only happens sometimes but once it happens retrying the delete never works. The only workaround I have at the moment is to manually delete the ENIs after the stack is done deleting my lambda and ends up in a failed state.

```
staging-msk-client-example-producer-stack | 5:51:27 AM | DELETE_FAILED        | AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup     | st... resource sg-0e6dbe0f6acf80e32 has a dependent object (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: DependencyViolation; Request ID: 1989aad9-1921-45d3-a413-d6179c4cc5e6; Proxy: null)
```

Comment: What is the actual error message you're seeing?

Comment: updated with error message

Comment: Can you reproduce this with a minimal stack containing just the lambda and the SG? What's your CDK version?